# Call a Function from a Class using Namespace

Tags: php, wordpress, class, namespaces

Sorry for my poor knowledge in PHP.

I have to call the `prepareFiles()` function from WordPress `functions.php` from class added by a plugin in WordPress. Here is the class (content of the file).

```
namespace FluentForm\Framework\Request;

trait FileHandler
{
    /**
     * Prepares HTTP files for Request
     *
     * @param array $files
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareFiles($files = [])
    {
        foreach ($files as $key => &$file) {
            $file = $this->convertFileInformation($file);
        }

        return $files;
    }
    
    protected function convertFileInformation($file)
    {
        $fileKeys = array('error', 'name', 'size', 'tmp_name', 'type');

        if ($file instanceof File) {
            return $file;
        }

        $file = $this->fixPhpFilesArray($file);

        if (is_array($file)) {
            $keys = array_keys($file);
            sort($keys);

            if ($keys == $fileKeys) {
                if (UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE == $file['error']) {
                    $file = null;
                } else {
                    $file = new File($file['tmp_name'], $file['name'], $file['type'], $file['size'], $file['error']);
                }
            } else {
                $file = array_map(array($this, 'convertFileInformation'), $file);
                if (array_keys($keys) === $keys) {
                    $file = array_filter($file);
                }
            }
        }

        return $file;
    }
}
```

I need to call this `prepareFiles` function inside a function in WordPress theme's `functions.php` file which is hooked into a action.

I have no idea where to declare that namespace so that I can call it. Any help will be appreciated.

(Declaring that namespace in top of the `functions.php` and `use` in function returns a fatal PHP error, while `use` after namespace breaks the other functions.)

Thanks

Comment: this is a trait not class, so you cannot use it's functions outside a class.
Traits are used to solve multiple inheritance issue in PHP. not to use it from anywhere.
Instead you can call this method from a class that use this trait.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to find a class that use this trait.

Something like:

```
class SomeClass {
    use FileHandler;

   ...

}
```

Then you need to create an instance of that class, Like:

```
$obj = new SomeClass(...);
$obj->prepareFiles($files);
```

See this Manual from **php.net:**

[PHP: Traits - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)